# Can I marry Non-Eu in The UK as Eu Citizen?

Tags: uk, eu-citizens, weddings

I am Eu citizen working in UK and would like to marry a girl non-Eu living in Indonesia. Is it possible for her to come in the UK and marry here and then stay in the UK.

What documents we need and how long it take ?

Comment: Do you intend to live together in the UK after getting married?

Comment: You can certainly get married in the UK but the details depend on whether she intends to remain there with you, among other things.  If she does, then your question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  if she does not then she probably needs a marriage visitor visa, but there is a (small) chance that she could use an EEA family permit.  Which to use depends on the history of your relationship.

Comment: Given that you want to stay in the UK, this is off-topic, here and needs to go to [expatriates.se].